# Android app showing MainActivity before the activity started using startActivityForResult()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseUI Auth for implementing a sign-in flow in my app. To actually start the sign-in flow I am first creating an **AuthStateListener**

```
authStateListener = FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener { authObj ->
            val currUser = authObj.currentUser
            if (currUser == null)
                startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                        .build(),
                    SIGN_IN
                )
}
```

And then I am attaching the `authStateListener` object to the **FirebaseAuth** Instance in `onResume()`, like so

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(authStateListener)
}
```

Even then, on launching the app, first the MainActivity appears, and only after a few seconds does the FirebaseUI activity appear.

In summary, my question is how can I make the **FirebaseUI** activity be the first one that the user sees on launching the app, instead of the MainActivity?

Thanks for considering my question!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show FirebaseUIActivity when user opens the app, you need to remove the following code from your MainActivity entry in Manifest file and add the same to your FirebaseUIActivity.

```
intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

so your main activity will become

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
```

and your FirebaseUIActivity will become

```
<activity android:name=".FirebaseUIActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And once you are done with that, you need to call startActivity instead of startActivityForResult()

Comment: I am sorry if I put it in an unclear manner, but the **FirebaseUI** activity doesn’t actually exist in the code, instead I am calling it with the code in the _startActivityForResult()_ function, by building an intent, so I can’t actually assign it to be the launcher activity in the manifest file. Still, thanks for the answer.